# First button on a GridView not working

Tags: java, android, gridview, adt, adapter

My GridView is working perfectly but the first button doesn't work. All the other buttons work independently. Also, while debugging, I discovered that the onItemClickListener works perfectly, do the problem must come from the adapter. The class "Case" is used to treat each button on its own. The buttons are supposed to flip, changing from a bland orange image, to an image of a fruit. Here are my three classes:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    GridView gridView;
    EasyGame easyGame;
    public static Case[] cases;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cases = new Case[16];
        easyGame = new EasyGame(this);
        this.gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.Cases);
        this.gridView.setAdapter(easyGame);
        this.gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        cases[arg2].flip();
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class EasyGame extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    int[] photos = {R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.apricot, R.drawable.banana,
        R.drawable.cherry, R.drawable.grapes, R.drawable.green_apple,
        R.drawable.kiwi, R.drawable.lemon };

    ArrayList<Integer> nombres;

    public EasyGame(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        nombres = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            nombres.add(i);
            nombres.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(nombres);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 16;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MainActivity.cases[position].getImage();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridItemView=null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.case_view, null);
        } else {
            gridItemView = convertView;
        }
        ImageView image = (ImageView)gridItemView.findViewById(R.id.uneCase);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.flipped);
        MainActivity.cases[position] = (new Case(image, photos[nombres.get(position)]));
        return gridItemView;
    }

    public void setNombres(ArrayList<Integer> nombres){
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }
}
```

Class Case:

```
public class Case{

    private boolean flipped = false;
    private int image;
    private View imageView;
    private final int flippedImage = R.drawable.flipped;

    public Case(View imageView, int image){
        this.image = image;
        this.imageView=imageView;
    }

    public void flip() {
        flipped = !flipped;

        if (flipped==false)
            ((ImageView) imageView).setImageResource(flippedImage);
        else
            ((ImageView) imageView).setImageResource(image);
    }

    public boolean isFlipped() {
        return flipped;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Here are the XML files:

main_activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/Cases"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="4" 
        android:columnWidth="120dp">
  </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

case_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 

    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/uneCase"
    android:src="@drawable/flipped" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you click on the first item? Does it dissappear by any chance? OR it just won't switch to the image resource you passed in the `Case` constructor ?

Comment: @AndreiBogdan This is all there is to the program. There's no more code so it must be from here. The `onItemClick` gets called when I click on the first item. It also goes into the flip function like any other item...

Comment: Wow. Interesting. So the `onItemClick` is 100% called for the first item and it goes into the `flip()` method. Hmm. Could the `image` resource ID be 0 ? In fact if you set it to 0 it should remove the image inside  `ImageView` altogether (if i'm not mistaken). It's worth a shot, sysout the `image` value and check.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan Just tried it. The `image` resource ID changes every time so everything is in order. I don't know why it isn't working...

Comment: me neither. Could you post the layouts here as well? The one for the Activity and the one for the grid view item ?

Comment: haha, i'm starting to get angry here :)) The heck is wrong with this code. Could you bare with me and try to remove the `android:src="@drawable/flipped"` from the grid view item and see if it even gets set within the adapter (the default flipped image).
Also ... could you try placing a notifiDataSetChanged() after setting the `setOnItemClickListener` in the Activity? so it refreshes the adapter.

Comment: These are really stupid suggestions, but I have no proper ones, 'cause the thing should work already, I don't see a problem with it :))

Comment: And? No improvements, i'm guessing ... :)

Comment: @AndreiBogdan I tried removing the `android:src="@drawable/flipped"`... To no avail... I am not familiar with notifiDataSetChanged(). What does it do?

Comment: It's used when you change the `ArrayList` of items in your adapter and you want the listview/gridview to update it's layout with the new values. In your case it might recreate each cell and if someting went wrong the first time it might "correct" it, but it's kida'va stupid suggestion, it shouldn't do anything in your case, but anything's worth a shot at this point. :)

Comment: I really have no idea. If you say that `onItemClick` is called with position 0 and the `flip()` method is called and the line `((ImageView) imageView).setImageResource(image);` is run and `image` is != 0, then I give up. :) I'm out of ideas. Sorry. If you do manage to figure it out, do post an answer here ... i'm really curious.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan I know it's weird, which is why I posted it here (I don't post here very often). Thank you so much for bearing with me. I will keep you updated.

Comment: You could try one more thing. It just came to me. Try and set an `onClickListener` to the image itself, within the adapter, in `getView()` and in the callback call the `flip()` method. It might make a difference, for what reason, i can't say, but it's worth a shot. (You'll have to make the `position` `final` for this) 
OK. Now i'm really done :)) Good luck with it !